# Modify netplan configuration without apply until reboot

Tags: netplan

I need to modify the netplan configuration in .yaml to add some static routes but i dont want to apply (netplan apply) until the next reboot (will be restarted in quite a few days).

This is my plan:

- Add route with the command ip route add (will disappear in the next reboot).
- Add the same route in .yaml config file but i dont apply configuration.
- Restart the server in a few days (the static route of the .yaml shall be applied).

The reason for this is that when I do a netplan apply, I lose the virtual ip of keepalived and it doesn't fix until I reboot.

I would like to know if the netplan will only be applied when the server is restarted and not before. Is this possible?.

Comment: See `man netplan generate` for one clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can update the netplan yaml and then apply it without rebooting.  I would suggest that you check the yaml file first:

```
sudo netplan try
```

and then, if all is well with the syntax, you can apply it.

```
sudo netplan apply
```

But as you have found, if the routes were added manually, outside of netplan, then any routes you have added will be lost. Netplan does exactly what you would expect, it basically restarts networking.

Comment: Thanks!, but I think I haven't explained myself clearly. What i want is the opposite, update the netplan yaml but not apply and make sure that it is not applied automatically until the reboot.

Comment: Then, what am I missing. Just edit netplan and save the file. It won't automatically apply until the next reboot.